# Website building so maintenance is easier

Tags: html, css, web

I need to build a website at request of a local company. It is a company which has very wide range of products. They put all of them online. So I will make sure that I build up the website so I can easily maintain afterwards.

So, is there a way to make your navigation, header and footer fixed? Because, sometimes they add a new sort of product to their assortment, and so I don't need to change the navigation in all of their pages?

I only use html/css, because that are the only basics I've learned ATM.

Please help. Thx

Comment: Use a database. It will help you alot! I guess your website will become a webshop? You can always try "shoptrader" aswell.

Comment: When using PHP. you can make the header and footer come back on every page with a simple line of code like: <?php include('header.php'); So it is really easy. Without a language such as PHP you can't really build a nice webshop/website. with a lot of functionalities.

Comment: Thanks for the reaction. I think I need to learn some php!

Comment: PHP, Ruby, Python, Node.js... all you have is to add a dynamic language into the mix and life will be better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your website in html/css that's no problem. But you can add a little php to include your header and footer like so:

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>Your Title</title>

</head>

<body>
<?php include('header.php'); ?> // this is your header. You can include it on every page.

<?php include('home.php'); ?> // this is your homepage. You can change this to for example: about me, products, categories, contact. etc

<?php include('footer.php'); ?> // this is your footer. you can add it on everypage by using this comment. just like the header.

</body>
</html>
```

Then in your `home.php` You just make a html page like you did always.
PHP include docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

You can also use Require, info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)

Hope you will get it. it's really helpful!

Comment: Je bent waarschijnlijk een Nederlander? Ik denk dat het in het Nederlands iets vlotter zal gaan. Kan u mij anders mailen?

Comment: We don't speak Dutch on StackOverflow. but I can give you some information.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Can you mail me? laurensdecroix@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Using `PHP` you can do this. You have to create one file for header which is say "header.php" after that in your htmlpage you have to do like this :-

**main.php :-**

```
<html>


<head>

</head>

<body>
<?php include('header.php'); ?>

/* Rest of your html code */


<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
</body>

</html>
```

**header.php :-** It will contain all your header HTML part

**footer.php :-** It will contain all your footer HTML part

**Main Page :-**  It will contain your main container. Here you have to include header.php and footer.php file

You have to just include `header.php` and `footer.php` in every file.

Also make sure you have to create your file with extension `.php`

You can learn PHP from [HERE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/)

Comment: glad that it helps you. PHP is very simple language to learn. Also if you got your solution then don't forget to mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: PHP isn't a simple language to learn... You need to get it by trying an looking for tutorials.

Comment: @KeesSonnema See I was not a PHP developer. I started my career in HTML designing. But now I'm having an experience of 2 years in PHP and build various site. What I want to say that if you want to learn PHP seriously and with interest then it will be very easy for you :)

Comment: Yes that's true. I think I understood you wrong. If you really want to learn PHP it will be easy.

Comment: I just saw that he accepted my answer. but I will upvote yours :)

Comment: @KeesSonnema its ok np :) atleast he got what he want from stackoverflow